# SpringFox not finding jax-rs endpoints

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, wordnik, springfox

After solving [Using Springfox to document jax-rs services in a Spring app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32833737/using-springfox-to-document-jax-rs-services-in-a-spring-app), I now find that SpringFox's JSON reply doesn't show any APIs:

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "description": "Some description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "title": "My awesome API",
    "contact": {
      "name": "my-email@domain.org"
    },
    "license": {}
  },
  "host": "localhost:9090",
  "basePath": "/myapp"
}
```

Here's springfox-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResourceJSON" />
    <bean class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider" />
    <bean class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider" />
</beans>
```

This is in a properties file:

```
swagger.resourcePackage=org.myapp
```

Swagger is configured to find the implementation classes using the reflective jax-rs scanner:

```
@Component
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    @Value("${swagger.resourcePackage}")
    private String resourcePackage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        ReflectiveJaxrsScanner scanner = new ReflectiveJaxrsScanner();
        scanner.setResourcePackage(resourcePackage);
        ScannerFactory.setScanner(scanner);

        ClassReaders.setReader(new DefaultJaxrsApiReader());

        SwaggerConfig config = ConfigFactory.config();
        config.setApiVersion(apiVersion);
        config.setBasePath(basePath);
    }

    public String getResourcePackage() {
        return resourcePackage;
    }

    public void setResourcePackage(String resourcePackage) {
        this.resourcePackage = resourcePackage;
    }
}
```

Here's the documentation configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class ApiDocumentationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Docket documentation() {
        System.out.println("=========================================== Initializing Swagger");
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
                .apiInfo(metadata());
    }

    @Bean
    public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return UiConfiguration.DEFAULT;
    }

    private ApiInfo metadata() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("My awesome API")
                .description("Some description")
                .version("1.0")
                .contact("my-email@domain.org")
                .build();
    }
}
```

And here's a sample class with the api annotations:

```
@Api(value = "activity")
@Service
@Path("api/activity")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public class ActivityService {

    @Autowired
    private CommandExecutor commandExecutor;
    @Autowired
    private FetchActivityCommand fetchActivityCommand;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Fetch logged-in user's activity", httpMethod = "GET", response = Response.class)
    @GET
    @Path("/mine")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Authorization(rejectionMessage = Properties.Authorization.NOT_LOGGED_IN_MESSAGE_PREFIX + "view your activities.")
    public List<Activity> listMyActivities(@Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        return buildActivityList(response, (UUID) request.getSession().getAttribute(Properties.Session.SESSION_KEY_USER_GUID));
    }
    ...
}
```

Why isn't it exposing the API? Would using the wordnik swagger library solve this, or improve the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately springfox doesn't support jax-rs annotations. I think you'll be better off using the swagger-core libraries.

Comment: @dilip, does swagger support jax-rs annotations directly?

Comment: Yes it does support it

Comment: @DilipKrishnan - Thank you, that was exactly the help I needed. I followed https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-1.X-Project-Setup-1.5 then added swagger-ui on top of that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By default SpringFox will document your REST services implemented using Spring MVC - it is as simple as adding `@EnableSwagger2` annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I managed to get SpringFox working with JAX-RS
At first I have added some swagger dependencies along with SpringFox:

```
dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.4.0")
    compile("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.4.0")
    compile("io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:1.5.8")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}
```

Then I have enabled JAX-RS (Jersey) with Swagger in my spring-boot application:

```
@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public static class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {

        BeanConfig swaggerConfig = new BeanConfig();
        swaggerConfig.setBasePath("/api");
        SwaggerConfigLocator.getInstance().putConfig(SwaggerContextService.CONFIG_ID_DEFAULT, swaggerConfig);

        packages(getClass().getPackage().getName(), ApiListingResource.class.getPackage().getName());
    }

}
```

Please note that all JAX-RS endpoints will be under `/api` context - otherwise it would conflict with Spring-MVC dispatcher

Finally we should add the swagger json generated for Jersey endpoints to Springfox:

```
@Component
@Primary
public static class CombinedSwaggerResourcesProvider implements SwaggerResourcesProvider {

    @Resource
    private InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider;

    @Override
    public List<SwaggerResource> get() {

        SwaggerResource jerseySwaggerResource = new SwaggerResource();
        jerseySwaggerResource.setLocation("/api/swagger.json");
        jerseySwaggerResource.setSwaggerVersion("2.0");
        jerseySwaggerResource.setName("Jersey");

        return Stream.concat(Stream.of(jerseySwaggerResource), inMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider.get().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

That's it! Now your JAX-RS endpoints will be documented by Swagger.
I used following sample endpoint:

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Component
@Path("/hello")
@Api
public class Endpoint {

    @GET
    @ApiOperation("Get message")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String message() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

Now when you start your server and go to http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html you will see the documentation for JAX-RS endpoints.
Use combobox on top of the page to switch to the documentation of  Spring MVC endpoints

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get the following error:

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'springfox.documentation.swagger.web.InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'springfox.documentation.swagger.web.InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider' in your configuration.

Where did you define InMemorySwaggerResourcesProvider?

Comment: @yeremy make sure that you have `@EnableSwagger2` annotation on your spring boot application class

Comment: @bedrin : I have been able to list the jersey endpoints on springfox swagger 2 . However the authorization button that was visible earlier has disappeared .. Can you please help here .

Please see: when I select default from drop down, the authorization button comes up

Comment: I can browse : http://localhost:5000/swagger-ui.html#/  , It's loading the UI for me, but  I a am getting error as "500 : {"timestamp":"2021-05-25T14:22:23.485+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"No message available","path":"/api/swagger.json"} http://localhost:5000/api/swagger.json"  Moreover , while I am trying to browse http://localhost:5000/api/swagger.json"    , I am getting  java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.getProperties(ResourceConfig.java:751)

Comment: Do you use AspectJ by any chance? Your NPE looks similar to this one: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6395

Answer (score 0):

Additional information about Authorization:

- If you want to add authentication for Jersey resources:

```
BeanConfig swaggerConfig = new BeanConfig();
Swagger swagger = new Swagger();

swagger.securityDefinition("apiKeyAuth", new ApiKeyAuthDefinition("Authorization", In.HEADER));
  
new SwaggerContextService().updateSwagger(swagger);
swaggerConfig.setBasePath("/api");
SwaggerConfigLocator.getInstance().putConfig(SwaggerContextService.CONFIG_ID_DEFAULT, swaggerConfig);
```

Of course this is Auth with JWT token. If you need Basic authentication use:

```
swagger.securityDefinition("basicAuth", new BasicAuthDefinition());
```

- If you need to add authetnctioan for Spring resources:

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerSpringConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.yourPackage"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .enable(true)
                .securitySchemes(Lists.newArrayList(apiKey()));
    }

    private ApiKey apiKey() {
        return new ApiKey("AUTHORIZATION", "Authorization", "header");
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityConfiguration security() {
        return new SecurityConfiguration(
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                ApiKeyVehicle.HEADER,
                "Authorization",
                null
        );
    }

}
```