# Swagger does not show / document my RESTful endpoints (JAX-RS, Spring-boot)

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, jax-rs, swagger

I have developed a RESTful web service in `Java` and `Spring boot` using `Jax-RS` and I would like to document it with `Swagger`. I have so far successfully managed to map the swagger-ui.html page on `http:8080/localhost/<context>/swagger-ui.html`. **Unfortunately, my RESTful endpoints do not appear anywhere**.

What I am using:

**pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Swagger configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    private TypeResolver typeResolver;

    @Bean
    public Docket api()
    {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.nick.java.webservice.services"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .enable(true)
                .apiInfo(getApiInfo())
                .tags(
                        new Tag("My web service", "Methods for my RESTful service")
                );
    }

    private ApiInfo getApiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("API Documentation")
                .description("API")
                .version("1.0")
                .contact(new Contact("mycompany", "", "nickath@mycompany.com"))
                .build();

        return apiInfo;
    }
```

**an example of the JAX-RS endpoints**

```
package org.nick.java.webservice.services;

@Path("/contextsapi")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
@Api(value = "Contexts API", produces = "application/json")
public interface ContextAPI {

    @Path("/contexts/contexts")
    @GET
    @ApiOperation( value = "get contexts",
                   response = List.class)
    List<Context> getContexts();
```

**screenshot of the swagger-ui.html page**

[image: screenshot]

as you can see, no 'get contexts' method has been generated

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

======= **UPDATE - SERVICE IMPLEMENTATION ========**

```
package  org.nick.java.webservice.services.impl;
@Service
@Api(value = "Contexts Api Impl", produces = "application/json", description = "desc")
@Path("/contextsapi")
public class ContextAPIImpl implements ContextAPI {

   @Override
   @GET
   @ApiOperation( value = "get contexts", response = List.class)
   public List<Context> getContexts(){
     //code ommitted
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

Finally I managed to solve my problem using the `Swagger2Feature` following the example from here https://code.massoudafrashteh.com/spring-boot-cxf-jaxrs-hibernate-maven-swagger-ui/

**Maven dependencies**

```
<cxf.version>3.1.15</cxf.version>
<swagger-ui.version>3.9.2</swagger-ui.version>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-rs-service-description-swagger</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger-ui.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**CxfConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class CxfConfig {

@Autowired
private Bus bus;


@Bean
public Server rxServer(){
    final JAXRSServerFactoryBean endpoint = new JAXRSServerFactoryBean();
    endpoint.setProvider(new JacksonJsonProvider());
    endpoint.setBus(bus);
    endpoint.setAddress("/swagger");
    endpoint.setServiceBeans(Arrays.<Object>asList(contextAPI());
    Swagger2Feature swagger2Feature = new Swagger2Feature();
    endpoint.setFeatures(Arrays.asList(swagger2Feature));
    return endpoint.create();
}


@Bean
public ContextAPI contextAPI(){
    return new ContextAPIImpl();
}
```

Now the swagger documentation is available on http://localhost:8080///swagger/api-docs?url=//swagger/swagger.json

To customize the endpoint's UI check the manual [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html)

Answer (score 0):

Swagger suppose not to show documentation for any `API client`. It will generate documentation for your service if there is any with swagger annotations.

To be confirmed about this, try creating a Spring `@service` and annotate with swagger annotations. The doc will be generated if every other aspects are taken care of. Since you can see the UI, I would assume the dependencies are right.

The idea here is, your task is to document your service and swagger helps with that. It's not your responsibility to generate/publish documentation for API(s) that your service consumes. Since you don't maintain the service, it doesn't make sense to maintain the documentation as well.

When I used Rest client for the first time, I also got a bit perplexed about this. But if you really think about it, this is expected and makes sense.

Comment: hi shakhawat , thanks for your response :) . I tried to do as you said ( annotate my @ service class with swagger annotations, but no doc was generated)
Actually I added swagger annotations to my service implementing the getContexts function 

@ Service
@ Api(value = "Contexts API", produces = "application/json", description = "description", hidden = false)
public class ContextAPIImpl implements ContextAPI {

@ Override
    @ ApiOperation( value = "get contexts",
            response = List.class)
    public List<Context> getContexts() { //code }

}
did I miss something?

Comment: can you also post your service implementation here? keep the package name as well.

Comment: check the updates in the question please, I added them there to be more readable :)

Comment: can you remove swagger annotations from the interface and change api selector to  `.apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())  `      ?

Comment: I did as you said and added .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/error.*")); to avoid basic-error-controller from being shown, but still no luck :/

Comment: Can you share your project? maybe on github/gitlab?

Comment: sorry for being late, I uploaded on my personal github account a repo with an example of the code since I am not allowed to publish the actual project on public, here it is :) https://github.com/Nickath/swaggerexample 
the endpoint for swagger is here http://localhost:8080/mycontext/swagger-ui.html#/

and the endpoint of the service is here http://localhost:8080/mycontext/services/jcpabecontextsapi/contexts/contexts

Comment: Can you follow this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877898/springfox-not-finding-jax-rs-endpoints

You need some additional work to document jersey endpoints by swagger

Comment: Thanks for your time :) I do not use the jersey implementation in my service, I found a solution for the apache cxf (which i use) as you can see in the post

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use **Swagger 2** i faced the same issue.
the issue is with the Docket you have implemented , correct regular expression can help.
Example :

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {                                    
@Bean
public Docket api() { 
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)  
      .select()                                  
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())              
      .paths(PathSelectors.any())                          
      .build();                                           
}
}
```

You can refer to the link above [Setting up Swagger 2 Example](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)
The Source code example is also from the above link.