# OpenAPI Swagger Documentation for Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

We are trying to generate swagger documentation for our project. It's springboot project but it has JAX-RS annotations like @Path, @Get, @Post etc.

We have added modified SpringBootApplication.java file to include swagger configurations like -

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@ImportResource({"/spring/context.xml"})
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "MFSWalletServ API's", version = "1.0", 
    description = "API Information"),
    servers = { @Server(description = "local", url = "http://localhost:8080"),
    @Server(description = "Stage", url = "https://msmaster.qa.paypal.com:12326")})

public class SpringBootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
          SpringApplication.run(RaptorApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Swagger page is showing up but no API's are coming up.

[image: Current Swagger page]

We might have to add some property or something to tell swagger where(package) to look for API's - but i am not sure where to add them. How can i add swagger documentation for our API's ?

Comment: Are you using Spring Fox? check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36104935/1442853) answer.

Comment: @Pablo: We are using open-api, but have tried springfox too. We looked at it and tried that approach; but it wasn't working for us

Comment: Please update your question with your project structure, a controller code and the pom with the related dependencies

Comment: Please consider using `springdoc` instead of `springfox`. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70178391/16572295 to find some more details.